# Python IndexError: list index out of range, issue with specific py library

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, soap, wsdl

I am trying to fetch data from a government site that contains all companies public data (open API) but the gov devs have released a very limited documentation on that. I found a python library that consumes the wsdl, it's name is litex.regon (can be foud on pypi). After initial troubles with setting up a working connection I stuck on a following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Adrian/path/core.py", line 19, in <module>
    search_nip('1250786189')
  File "C:/Users/Adrian/path/core.py", line 16, in search_nip
    print(api.full_report(str(result[0].Regon), report_name='PublDaneRaportDzialalnosciPrawnej'))
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\litex\regon\__init__.py", line 257, in full_report
    get_message_element(mesg, 0, '//DanePobierzPelnyRaportResult/text()')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Heres my def that should fetch report on a specific company (search based on a company id assigned during company regstration):

```
from litex.regon import REGONAPI, REGONAPIError

# SERVICE_URL = ("https://wyszukiwarkaregontest.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/wsdl/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.xsd")
SERVICE_URL = ("https://wyszukiwarkaregontest.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.svc")
USER_KEY = ("abcde12345abcde12345")


def search_nip(client_nip):
    api = REGONAPI(SERVICE_URL)
    api.login(USER_KEY)
    result = api.search(nip=client_nip)
    print(str(result[0].Nazwa))
    print(str(result[0].Regon))
    print(api.full_report(str(result[0].Regon), report_name='PublDaneRaportDzialalnosciPrawnej'))
    api.logout()

search_nip('1250786189')
```

`SERVICE_URL` and `USER_KEY` given in code are for working test env which is publicly available. The following is an excerpt from `__init__.py` for the `api.full_report`:

```
def full_report(self, regon, report_name):
    mesg = self.call(
        FULL_REPORT_ENVELOPE,
        regon=regon,
        report_name=report_name
    )
    result = objectify.fromstring(
        get_message_element(mesg, 0, '//DanePobierzPelnyRaportResult/text()')[0]
    )

    if not len(result):
        raise REGONAPIError('Getting full report failed.')

    return result[0].dane
```

and the final code is the FULL_REPORT_ENVELOPE which is (I guess) responsible for the wsdl communication:

```
FULL_REPORT_ENVELOPE = '''\
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07">
<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<wsa:To>{api.service_url}</wsa:To>
<wsa:Action>http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/IUslugaBIRzewnPubl/DanePobierzPelnyRaport</wsa:Action>
</soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
      <ns:DanePobierzPelnyRaport>
         <ns:pRegon>{regon}</ns:pRegon>
         <ns:pNazwaRaportu>{report_name}</ns:pNazwaRaportu>
      </ns:DanePobierzPelnyRaport>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
'''
```

I would appreciate all help! Thank you!

Comment: what is printed here:
print(str(result[0].Regon)) ?

Comment: REGON is second (after NIP) ID assigned to a legal entity in Poland. it's numeric.